# Perform Function on 1 Column Table in Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle

I have a table with 1 column:

```
id 
1
2
3
4
5
6
7
8
9
```

and I want the following output:

```
11
22
33
41
52
63
71
82 
93
```

I am using Oracle.

Comment: What's your expect result logic?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Tell us what you've tried and why it didn’t meet your needs. This demonstrates that you’ve taken the time to try to help yourself, it saves us from reiterating obvious answers, and most of all it helps you get a more specific and relevant answer! See also: [ask]

Comment: Shrikant, if your IDs are sequential without breaks then it looks like your last digit is a mod 3 of the ID. If my assumption is correct then following might help: SELECT cast(number + 1 as varchar(10)) + cast((number) % 3 + 1 as varchar(10))
FROM master..spt_values
WHERE type = 'P';

Answer (score 1):

you can try like below using case when

```
select case when (id*11)<=33 then (id*11) 
            when (id*11)>33 and (id*11)<70 then (id*11)-3
            else  (id*11)-6 end as col
             from your_table
```

[demo link](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=c96c04368b1532a5c5dcdb73ac26c0a8)

output

```
COL
11
22
33
41
52
63
71
82
93
```